# Как получить или отслеживать кто нажал на реакцию в сообщении? Discord bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, discord-api

Есть дискорд бот. Нужно создать реакции под сообщениями, которые бот отправляет, и получать информацию, о том, кто нажал на какую реакцию.

Answer (score 1):

**POST_ID** - ID сообщения, реакцию под которым нужно отследить.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.message_id == config.POST_ID:
        channel = client.get_channel(payload.channel_id) #канал
        message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id) #сообщение
        user = get(message.guild.members, id=payload.user_id) #пользователь, который поставил реакцию
        emoji = str(payload.emoji)
```

**Дополнено:**

Вместо `on_raw_reaction_add(payload)` можно использовать `on_reaction_add(reaction, user)`. Подробнее опять таки, в [документации](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=reaction#discord.on_reaction_add).

Comment: А что такое payload?

Comment: `payload()` - необработанные данные полезной нагрузки события.RawReactionActionEvent

Вообще, я брал это из [документации](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=reaction#discord.on_reaction_add), так что своими словами нормально не объясню.